# Let $ f : \mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C$ is analytic . Show that the following conditions each imply that $f$ is a constant function

Tags: complex-analysis

1. $\operatorname{Re} f(z) > 0$ for all z $\in \mathbb C$
2. $|f(z)| \in \mathbb Z$ for all z $\in \mathbb C$.
3. $ f(z) = i$ when $z = (1 + \frac{k}{n}) + i$ for every positive integer k.

please give me hint .

Thank  you

Comment: If $\text{Re}(f(z)) > 0$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, then how is it  possible that $f(z) = i$ for any values of $z$? Remember that $\text{Re}(i) = 0$.

Comment: @Svinepels I think the OP meant that each of the above three conditions implies that the function is constant.

Comment: What conditions do you know that force a holomorphic function (entire or not) to be constant?

Comment: I also assume you want $n$ to be a (positive) integer...?

Comment: For case $II$, I think we can argue on continuity of **norm function**

Comment: And for case 3) I believe we can use the maximum modulus principle

Comment: @ Svinepels: Each of three conditions implies that the function is constant.

Comment: In (1) and (2) ,we can use picard theorem

Answer (score 3):

**Hints**

For (1), consider $g(z) = \exp(-f(z))$. Then $g$ is bounded.

For (2), use the open mapping theorem. The image of $f$ is contained in the union of circles $|z| = k$.

For (3), consider $g(z) = f(z)-i$ and use the identity theorem. (What are the zeros of $g$?)

Comment: @ mrf :For (2) , I am agree with your point that image  of f is contained in the union of circles $|z|$ = k, by the maximum module principle $f$   is   constant on each circle, How to conclude that f  is constant on $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @Struggler If you choose $k\notin\mathbb{Z}$ the maximum is not attained at the boundary, hence $f$ is constant

Comment: .... that i take f(z)-i = g(z) i don't know the further step  how to show that g(z) =0 @ mrf  can u more eloboarate ..... that