# Is the given function is entire or not?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f\colon\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ be analytic.
>   $f(z)=i$ when $z=(1+\frac kn)+i$ for every positive integer $k$.

[image]

My attempt; I know that Identity theorem said that the given functions f and g holomorphic on a connected open set D, if f = g on some non-empty open subset of D, then f = g on D. Thus a holomorphic function is completely determined by its values on a (possibly quite small) neighborhood in D. i know that idendity theorem satisfying this f(z)  but

Here I don't know how to prove that f(z) is constant or non constant,,

Pliz help me tell me the solution,,,,

Comment: The search terms "analytic function constant" triggers a memory in my mind about bounded holomorphic functions being constant. That may help.

Comment: can u help me to write the exact proof @ neal

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is $n$? Is it a fixed natural number? If so, then the statement is false.

Comment: @ jose carlos santos        ya .....n is a natural number

Comment: n is  a positive integer @ jose carlos santos

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Let $ f : \mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C$ is analytic . Show that the following conditions each imply that $f$ is a constant function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/825704/let-f-mathbb-c-rightarrow-mathbb-c-is-analytic-show-that-the-following)

Comment: If the condition reads “for every positive integers $k$ and $n$”, then the function is constant. If $n$ is fixed, then a suitable periodic non constant function will do.

Comment: suppose i take k = 4 and n = 2 that mean z= 2 + i  so f(z) = f(2+i) = i    ,  how can it can be  constant @egreg  ,,,can u pliz elaborate my doubt,,,

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\sin(z)$ is $2\pi$-periodic. Now scale the argument and the result to get a non-trivial function verifying the condition, i.e. try with e.g.
$f(z) = a \sin ( bz-c)$ for suitable choices of $a,b$ and $c$.

Comment: im not getting ,,how can i scale argument  can u pliz more elaborate@ H.H Rugh